# How to dynamically disable radioButton group

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I create one element in my radioGroup like this:

```
var selectorLay1 = document.createElement('input');
        var selectorLay1Atributes = {
            'type': 'radio',
            'class': "selectorLay1",
            'id': "radioLay1",
            'name': "layouts",
            'onchange': "mv.createLayout(1,1)"};
```

I have different elements like this. But they all have the same name: `'layouts'`. 
How to find all of this elements and disable them dynamically.

Comment: You realise that this will (certainly *seems to*) create multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: only the name attribute is the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('layouts');
for (var i = 0, r=radios, l=r.length; i < l;  i++){
    r[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName for `getElementsByName`

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('layouts');
for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i<len; i++){
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rHfus/).

This will select the relevant elements with the `name` of `layouts`, and then, in the `for {...}` loop, iterate over those elements and set the `disabled` property.

Using a simple function approach:

```
function disableByName(elName){
    var els = document.getElementsByName(elName);
    if (els !== null){
        for (var i = 0, len = els.length; i<len; i++){
            els[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}

var button = document.getElementById('radioDisable');

button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    disableByName('layouts');
}, false);
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rHfus/1/).

Or, if you'd prefer, you can extend the Object prototype to allow you to directly disable those elements returned by the `document.getElementsByName()` selector:

```
Object.prototype.disable = function(){
    var that = this;
    for (var i = 0, len = that.length; i<len; i++){
        that[i].disabled = true;
    }
    return that;
};

document.getElementsByName('layouts').disable();
```

[Simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rHfus/3/).